# How to index and automate processing of list using input csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have csv input file, lets call it *heights.csv*. my example file has only four lines but it cannot be limited.
The first column contains just irrelevant name, the second one contains values I want to process as integers.

1000,57020,
2003,56095,
2007,55964,
3001,57020,

I would like to perform action like this:

first_read_a = value of the first line + first random.randint(500, 1000)
second_read_a = value of the first line + first_read - value of the next line
third_read_a = value of the first line + random.randint(500, 1000) - value of the next line
fourth_read_a = value of the first line + random.randint(500, 1000) - value of the next line

and so on if the list would be longer until the last line where there's no next line and no next value to subtract.
results of the process must be stored and indexed somehow because the next task
is to perform similar action backwards, using generated values.

first_read_b = value of the last line + fourth_read_a - next to last line value
and so on until the second line from the beginning of the list this time, not the first one.
 i have sample code but it is very limited and I'd like to ask You for example of efficient solution.

```
import random
a = [57020, 56095, 55964, 57020]

compute = input(">")

if compute == 1: 
    read_0a = random.randint(500,1000)                
    read_1a = a[0] + read_0a - a[1]                 
    read_2a = a[1] + random.randint(500,2300) - a[2]
    read_3a = a[2] + random.randint(500,2300) - a[3]

    read_1b = a[3] + read_3a - a[2]              
    read_2b = a[2] + read_2a - a[1]                


    print read_0a, read_1a, read_2b, read_2a, read_1b, read_3a
    print read_1a + read_2a + read_3a
    print read_0a + read_1b + read_2b
```

The deal is to develope the script to such form, which would let to process input *.csv file and generate suitable integers in the way it is done in my example script but without need to define the list ['a' list in example] by hand and to put instruction for every single '*read*' how it has to be generated. I would like to know, how to index a csv file and how can I access indexed items as integers, not strings and how to trigger those integers by index.
**---------------------------------------------------------------**
Let me explain more.
We have eyquem's advanced script:

```
import csv
import random
```

with open('heights.csv','rb') as f:
    a = [int(row[1]) for row in csv.reader(f)]
    print 'a==',a

compute = input(">")

if compute == 1:
    read_a = dict((i+1,a[i] + random.randint(500,2300) - a[i+1])
                  for i in xrange(0,len(a)-1) )

```
read_a[0] = read_a[1] - a[0] + a[1]

read_b = dict( (i, a[len(a)-1] + read_a[len(a)-i] - a[len(a)-i-1])
               for i in xrange(1,len(a)-1))
print read_a, read_b
```

and we get the example result:

this is input list: `a== [57020, 56095, 55964, 57020]`

and generated 'reads':
`{0: 1637, 1: 2562, 2: 1991, 3: 4} {1: 1060, 2: 2916}`


Let's check:
**57020 + 1637 - 2562 = 56095** [correct!, because it is equal to the second value on the list]
So let's take the second value on the list and go forth:
**56095 + 1991 - 1060 = 57026** [wrong, because it is not equal to the third value on the list]
so now the rest is gonna give us wrong results.
The the right relationship of dependence is as following:
Let me show You my desired result, using example values of 'reads' generated with my [primitive]first script posted:
a = [**57020, 56095, 55964, 57020**]
**57020**      #the 1st value on the list
**+712**       #read_0a = random.randint(500,1000)
**-1637**      #read_1a = 1st + read_0a - 2nd
**[=]56095**   #the 2nd value on the list
**+772**       #read_2b = 3rd + read_2a - 2nd
**-903**       #read_2a = 2nd + random.randint(500,2300) - 3rd
**[=]55964**   #the 3rd value on the list
**+1279**      #read_1b = 4th] + read_3a - 3rd
**-223**       #read_3a = 3rd + random.randint(500,2300) - 4th
**[=]5720**    #the 4th value on the list
And that's it.
 When you run from the 1st value on the list and will do + and - succesive values of generated 'reads' in the way I show above, You will get the last value, in our example the 4th one, gaining on the way the 2nd and the 3rd value.
Now take a look at the final check of generated *reads*:
**check_a = read_1a + read_2a + read_3a

check_b = read_0a + read_1b + read_2b**
... and You'll see that **sum of values in check_a = sum of values in check_b**
The above check is authoritative only if the first line and the last line has the same  value - in example file it is 57020.
If the first line and the last line has different value the check has to be like this:
**first_line_value - last_line_value=(read_0a + read_1b + read_2b) - (read_1a + read_2a + read_3a)**.
 So we can say in more adequate way that:
 **first_line_value - last_line_value = sum of reads_backward - sum of reads_onward**
I hope it'll help You to understand what it has to be achieved.
 and thank You for Your patience.
**---------------------------------------------------------------**

[eyquem](/users/551449/eyquem)'s script works really great!
 and completely implemets my instruction that has been given to this moment but at the end of my question I would like You to consider several extra things, that, I hope, will not require to rewrite the whole code
**1]**The first one is the input, 'heights.csv' file.
Is it possible that the program would accept values with decimal point '**.**'
but just ignore it during one's computations??
The input csv file would be like this:
**1000,57.020,

2003,56.095,

2007,55.964,

3001,57.020,**


but nevertheless to compute 'reads',the integers like: **57020, 56095, 55964, 57020** would be used
**2]**The next thing is auto recomputation ability.
 Sometimes, during the computation our 'reads' appear as negative values with minus, for example:
`a== [57020, 56095, 55964, 57020]

read_a== {1: 1984, 2: 2128, 3: -452}

read_b== {1: 604, 2: 1997, 3: 1059}`

in this result we see **'-452'**
In this case the script should just recompute until there's no negative value among 'reads'
**3]** The last thing is an output file, for example 'output.txt'
Is it possible to generate such file containg generated 'reads'?
The template would be like this:
**[1]** # order number in square bracket
**1=1000** # name taken from the first column of input file, always preceded with '1='
**4=2118** # generated 'read', always preceded with '4='

**[2]**
**1=2003**
**4=3043**

**[3]**
**1=**
**4=2054**

**[4]**
**1=2007**
**4=2185**

**[5]**
**1=**
**4=2263**

**[6]**
**1=3001**
**4=1207**
As You see the name taken from the first column of input file, always preceded with '1=' has to appear for the first and the last 'read' and then only for all the 'backward reads'

Comment: This seems pretty arbitrary. It might really help to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, I tried as hard as I can to make it understood and conceptualized from what's this script for exactly because full explanation would insert unnecessary quite complicated theory of one of land surveying routines in my country.

Comment: The script you attribute to me was written by eyquem.

Comment: @daikini You should have made clear from the very beginning that it is essential that the first and the last lines of the file have the same value. It is the required condition under which sum(read_a)==sum(read_b)

Comment: I'd certainly say so if it would be true and sorry if my example introduced You into mistake. This is only coincidence that the first and the last line of the file has the same value in my example. It is not the rule. Sorry for that.

Comment: @daikini You're too kind, I didn't do a reproach. No, I wasn't induced in mistake because I didn't notice this characteristics of the file's content you wrote (4 lines beginning and ending with 57020) . But then, now I don't understand why this remark of you: _Now take a look at the final check of generated reads: check_a = read_1a + read_2a + read_3a check_b = read_0a + read_1b + read_2b ... ... and You'll see that sum of values in check_a = sum of values in check_b_ . Since ``read_3b`` is equal to ``read_0a``, it's the same as ``sum(read_a)==sum(read_b)``

Comment: @daikini You should find alone how to code with this : remove the point before applying ``int()`` function. Removing a character consists in replacing it with ``""``

Comment: In example case, when the first and the last line of the file has the same value the chceck is Ok but You're right that otherwise is incorrect. If the first line and the last line has different values @eyquem The check has to be like this: first_line_value - last_line_value=(read_0a + read_1b + read_2b) - (read_1a + read_2a + read_3a). So we can say in more adequate way that: first_line_value - last_line_value = sum of reads_a[backwards] - sum of reads_b[onward]

Comment: @eyquem Alright, I'm gonna try to figure it out. Thanks for advanced help. Greetngs from Poland.

Comment: @daikini I could give you the answer for all the points, but it wouldn't be very pedagogic for you. It's the reason. -- I have studied the condition of positive numbers only. This condition must be respected by numbers in ``read_a`` as in ``read_b`` , I presume ? I treated this condition mathematically but have a bug. I suspend this problem for a moment, I won't drop it but I have affairs to do.

Comment: @eyquem Sure, I understand :) I'm very glad because You helped more than I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I hope you worked with success on your problem.

Did you find how to manage with `'.'` in the values ? That was simple:

```
replace('.','')
```

For me, I think the following code fulfills all the requirements. I hope it wasn't a homework and you learned something.

```
import csv
import random
from sys import exit

with open('heights.csv','rb') as f:
    names,a = {},{}
    for k,row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        names[k] = row[0]
        a[k]     = int(row[1].replace('.',''))
    print names
    print 'a==',a
    L = len(a)

compute = input(">")

if compute == 1:

    if a[1] - a[0] <= 1000 and all(a[i] - a[i-1] <= 2300 for i in xrange(2,L)):

        read_b = {L-1 : random.randint( max(500,a[1]-a[0]), 1000 ) }
        read_a = {1   : a[0] + read_b[L-1] - a[1] }

        for i in xrange(2,L):
            read_b[L-i] = random.randint( max(500,a[i]-a[i-1]), 2300 )
            read_a[i] = a[i-1] + read_b[L-i] - a[i]

    else:
        exit("The file can't be treated because of the relative values of "
             "the following couples of lines : "+\
             ('(0,1) ' if 1000 < a[1] - a[0] else "")+\
             ' '.join(repr((i-1,i)) for i in xrange(2,L) if 2300 < a[i] - a[i-1]))



    with open('output.txt','w') as fw:
        fw.write('[1]\n1={}\n4={}\n\n[2]\n1={}\n4={}\n\n'.\
                 format(names[0],read_b[L-1],names[1],read_a[1]))

        fw.writelines('[{}]\n1=\n4={}\n\n[{}]\n1={}\n4={}\n\n'.\
                      format(str(2*k-1),read_b[L-k],str(2*k),names[k],read_a[k])
                      for k in xrange(2,L))                           



    # display of the execution

    print 'read_a== %s\nread_b== %s\n\n' % (read_a,read_b)+\
          ''+\
          ('\n'.join(('  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (y,a[y])+\
                      '\n    +read_b[%s] == %s' % (str(L-y-1), read_b[L-y-1])+\
                      '\n    -read_a[%s] == %s' % (str(y+1)  ,-read_a[y+1]  ) )
                     for y in xrange(L-1)) )+\
          '\n  a[%s] ========== %s ******\n\n' % (L-1,a[L-1])+\
          ''+\
          ('\n'.join(('  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (y,a[y])+\
                      '\n    +read_a[%s] == %s' % (y  , read_a[y]  )+\
                      '\n    -read_b[%s] == %s' % (L-y,-read_b[L-y]) )
                     for y in xrange(L-1,0,-1)) )+\
          '\n  a[%s] ========== %s ******\n\n' % (0,a[0])+\
          ''+\
          'sum(read_a.values())== %s\nsum(read_b.values())== %s' %\
          (sum(read_a.values()),sum(read_b.values()))
```

.

Explanation:

.

The values of **read_b** variables are created by `randint()` . If the bounds in each  `randint()` are considered untouchable constraints,  the condition of positiveness is consequently on the values of the **read_a** variables.

You wrote :

```
read_0a = random.randint(500,1000)  
read_1a = a[0] + read_0a - a[1]
```

that is to say

```
read_a[0] = random.randint(500,1000)  
read_a[1] = a[0] + read_a[0] - a[1]
# nota bene: read_a[0] is in fact read_b[len(a)-1]
```

The condition **0 <= read_a[1]** is verified only if **0 <= a[0] + read_a[0] - a[1]**

that is to say if  **a[1] - a[0] <= read_a[0]** (E)

So, there is 3 cases:

- if **a[1] - a[0] <= 500** is True, then   (E) is always True for any value **read_a[0]** defined by `read_a[0] = random.randint(500,1000)`
- if **500 <= a[1] - a[0]  <= 1000** is True , then (E) is True only for value **read_a[0]** defined by   `read_a[0] = random.randint(a[1] - a[0]  ,1000)`
- if **1000 < a[1] - a[0]** is True , it is impossible to find a value between 500 and 1000 to be the value of **read_a[0]** so as the value of **read_a[1]** will be positive.

We may think to reiterate the instruction `read_a[0] = random.randint(500,1000)` that is to say `read_b[len(a)-1] = random.randint(500,1000)`  until the value of **read_a[0]** respects the condition **read_a[1] >= 0**.

But  if **1000 < a[1] - a[0]**  , there would be an endless loop. This means that the values in the file can't be any integer without condition : they must verify some conditions in order that all the **read_a** values be positive. And I put the verification of this condition in the code.

.

It's the same for the other values in **read_a** with bounds

```
randint(500,2300)
```

Comment: @eyquem Oh, no, it is neither homework, nor for commercial usage, don't worry. Your work is really great aid as I know exactly what's this script for and this help me to understand some advanced techniques of programming in python. Really, really thanks! And I just hope that completing the task gave You just a little satisfaction or at least any tiny programming skills improvement. Once again thanks.

Comment: @eyquem There's something not quite Ok, because the script generates too many reads. We have 8 reads generated instead of 6 needed with our example input file, so there's excess of 2 reads. If You examine output.txt file, You're gonna see, that the last point is twice.

Comment: @daikini Satisfaction in succeeding to help someone isn't little. And Python is fun too. -- I forgot to mention that I considered the bounds of ``randint()`` calls as definitive and unmodifiable. If it is the case, the algorithm should be different. It depends of the program's aim. say me if this point is definitive. -- See again the code, I changed to snippet concerning the display of execution. The reason is that ``print 'aaa\nbbb'+'\nccc'`` is faster to be executed than ``print 'aaa' print 'bbb' print 'ccc'``

Comment: @daikini When you will consider this problem can be closed, it will be fine for me that you upvote my answer(s) and accept one of them (by clicking on the chevron shape stripe under the button to downvote, on the left) if you judge them enough valuable. I inform you because your new on stackoverflow.

Comment: @daikini You just have to eliminate ``fw.write('[{}]\n1=\n4={}\n\n[{}]\n1={}\n4={}\n'.\
                      format(str(2*L-1),read_b[1],str(2*L),names[L-1],read_a[L-1]))``

Comment: @daikini ERRATUM In an above comment: _"I considered the bounds of randint() calls as definitive and unmodifiable. If it is **NOT** the case, the algorithm should be **different**."_

Comment: @daikini So, it's over ? Maybe you could upvote my second answer, because of the (moderate) elevation of my brain's temperature that the problem caused to me this morning :)) I don't think it's forbidden by the rules. Thank you PS: this answer this morning, and the other yesyerday, in fact. PPS: have you other questions ? Now I know well the problem and my brain's motor is hot :)

Comment: @eyquem Your script is really finished and fill my conditions but there's something that could be enhanced. If You change value of any given height in input file, for example change 57.020 in the first line to 50.020, You'll get the error message because difference between 50.020 and the second value that is 56.095 exceeds our 500,2300 limit. In this case the script should just generate one, or two or more random(500,4000) read_a/read_b pairs, to compensate the level of excess.

Comment: To make it in most efficient way, every extra-generated read_b should be as low as possible, like random(1,500) and then every extra-generated read_a should be as high as possible, the highest acceptable value is even 4000.

Comment: @eyquem If You want to, I will post another question using Your final answer script as base. But i have no idea how can i title this problem. Greetings.

Comment: @eyquem And one more thing...when i click on the next chevron, it turns green and the first one previously clicked turns again white, i'm not sure if it helped You:)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import random

with open('fofo.txt','rb') as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f)
    a = [int(row[1]) for row in rd]
    print 'a==',a

(.... to be continued by daikini's code...)
```

`rd = csv.reader(f)` is an iterator that returns one row of the csv file when stimulated with `rd.next()` or during a for loop. 
The file MUST be opened in reading binary mode `'rb'`

Placing the items in a list `a` just indexes them by the index of the list.

.

The following code has been edited:

-- I corrected `a[len(a)-1]` with `a[len(a)-i]` in the definition of `read_b`

-- I put the `random.randint(500,2300)` in a list `R`  out of the definition of `read_a`

-- There is no real interest to define `read_a[0]` by `read_a[0] = a[1] + read_a[1] - a[0]` . In fact `read_a[0]` is precisely `R[0]` . I eliminated this line

-- In fact , it is also possible to define `read_b[3]` . It turns out to be `read_a[0]` ; Hence `R[0]==read_a[0]==read_b[3]`  !--

.

```
import csv
import random

with open('heights.csv','rb') as f:
    a = [int(row[1]) for row in csv.reader(f)]
    print 'a==',a

compute = input(">")
if compute == 1:

    R = [random.randint(500,2300) for j in xrange(len(a)-1)]

    read_a = dict((i+1,a[i] + R[i] - a[i+1])
                  for i in xrange(0,len(a)-1) )

    read_b = dict( (i, a[len(a)-i] + read_a[len(a)-i] - a[len(a)-i-1])
                   for i in xrange(1,len(a)))




    print 'R==',R
    print 'read_a==',read_a
    print 'read_b==',read_b
    print

    for y in xrange(len(a)-1):
        print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (y,a[y])
        print '      +R[%s]    == %s' % (str(y),R[y])
        print '    -read_a[%s] == %s' % (str(y+1),-read_a[y+1])
    print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (len(a)-1,a[len(a)-1])
    print '\n'

    #print ' a['+str(len(a)-1)+']==',a[len(a)-1]
    for y in xrange(len(a)-1,0,-1):
        print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (y,a[y])
        print '    +read_a[%s] == %s' % (y,read_a[y])
        print '    -read_b[%s] == %s' % (len(a)-y,-read_b[len(a)-y])
    print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (0,a[0])
    print '\n'

    print 'sum(read_a.values())==',sum(read_a.values())
    print 'sum(read_b.values())===',sum(read_b.values())
```

.

Finally, we notice that `read_b.values() = R[::-1]` then the code can be simplified to:

```
import csv
import random

with open('heights.csv','rb') as f:
    a = [int(row[1]) for row in csv.reader(f)]
    print 'a==',a

compute = input(">")

if compute == 1:

    read_b = dict((j+1,random.randint(500,2300)) for j in xrange(len(a)-1))

    read_a = dict((i,a[i-1] + read_b[len(a)-i] - a[i])
                  for i in xrange(1,len(a)) )



    print 'read_a==',read_a
    print 'read_b==',read_b
    print

    for y in xrange(len(a)-1):
        print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (y,a[y])
        print '    +read_b[%s] == %s' % (str(len(a)-y-1),read_b[len(a)-y-1])
        print '    -read_a[%s] == %s' % (str(y+1),-read_a[y+1])
    print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (len(a)-1,a[len(a)-1])
    print '\n'

    for y in xrange(len(a)-1,0,-1):
        print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (y,a[y])
        print '    +read_a[%s] == %s' % (y,read_a[y])
        print '    -read_b[%s] == %s' % (len(a)-y,-read_b[len(a)-y])
    print '  a[%s] ========== %s ******' % (0,a[0])
    print '\n'

    print 'sum(read_a.values())==',sum(read_a.values())
    print 'sum(read_b.values())==',sum(read_b.values())
```

These codes can be used for any number of lines >= 2

.

Concerning the condition of positive numbers:

Numbers in `read_b` are the first to be computed. So I search for the  condition that makes `read_b` always positive:

> Since read_a[i] = a[i-1] +
>   read_b[len(a)-i] - a[i]
>
> =>  read_b[len(a)-i]  = read_a[i] + a[i] - a[i-1]
>
> => read_b[j]  = read_a[len(a)-j] + a[len(a)-j] - a[len(a)-j-1]

Since we must have 0 < read_a[len(a)-j]

> =>  a[len(a)-j] - a[len(a)-j-1]  < read_a[len(a)-j] + a[len(a)-j] -
>   a[len(a)-j-1]
>
> => a[len(a)-j] - a[len(a)-j-1]   < read_b[j]
>
> => we must have  a[len(a)-j] - a[len(a)-j-1]  + 1 <= read_b[j]

Then condition

```
max(a[len(a)-j] - a[len(a)-j-1]  + 1 , 500))  <= read_b[j]
```

Am I right ?

Comment: Ahhhhhh... So he wanted to know how to read a csv file? I had to look at this five times to understand why it just looked like you copied his code and provided it as an answer!

Comment: I suppose it is what he wants, it seems so simple to me, but what else than a problem of reading a file, I wonder ?

Comment: Surely csv is overkill for grabbing just the second column of a file?

Comment: @kojiro When I don't use a parser to read a file, there is always someone to tell me that one must never use built-in functions or regexes to read a file....

Comment: @eyquem Your script seems just fantastic. Really thanks You got round to anlyze my lenghty and unclear query. If it won't abuse You, please, take a look at the third final part I wrote in to my question. And thanks a lot.

Comment: @daikini OK, but what part ? ``sum(read_a)`` is ``check_a`` and same for other sum. By the way, I've just corrected the code in the middle. I had done a mistake of file, there wasn't the line ``R = [random.randint(500,2300) for j in xrange(len(a)-1)]`` . Anyway, this code is intermediary before the last one without ``R``

Comment: @eyquem The one that begins with 'eyquem's script works really great!' Thanks for Your work.

Comment: @eyquem Maybe it will be helpfull but read_b seems to be always positive somehow during my all-day tests and only read_a sometimes gives negative values because these values are strictly forced. Besides 'negative value check' is only a minor improvement - unnecessarily I bothered You with this matter, what I see now.

Comment: @daikini Values ``read_b`` will always be positive as long as they are created by instructions ``randint(500,1000)`` and ``randint(500,2300)`` . I showed that it's the fact, in one of the codes: ``R = [ random.randint(500,2300) for j in xrange(1,len(a)) ]``  appeared to be ``read_b[::-1]``

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

compute = input(">")

if compute == 1:

    # If you have to store it anyway, might as well go whole-hog:
    vals = [int(l.split(",")[1]) for l in open("heights.csv").readlines()]

    reads[0] = vals[0] + randint(500, 1000)
    for i in xrange(len(vals) - 1):
        reads.append(vals[i-1] + randint(500, 1000) - vals[i])
        # not sure what to do with the last value
```

Comment: First i would like to thank You for help. The last script You posted has started to fill my request and it's almost right direction. Please, take a look in my edited question to better understand what else has to be done.

Comment: @diakini I think my example already does what you described, including demonstrating how to open and parse the csv file, transform clean strings to ints. The only thing it doesn't do is "perform similar action backwards". I assume you can adapt it to that or ask a more specific question?

Comment: @kojiro yes, You're right and I think it's really great what You've done with just a few lines of python's code. I would ask You to check the second part of explanation I've just added. I hope it will let You fully understand the idea.

Comment: @daikini Did you read my answer ? I have just seen that you edited your question and I will study that. But in my answer there is the backward treatment

Comment: @eyquem Yes I did read. Sorry for my silence about Your solution. Your second script that is closer to the goal, I guess, has the same 'weakness' that kojiro's one. There's some kind of malfunction in exactly backward treatment because when firstly we go forth, values we get as a result depend mainly on random generated integers, except the second 'read' which depends on strict arithmetical relation and belongs rather to backward 'reads'. The second part, when we move backwards is more complex because all values we gain during this treatment depend on strict arithmetical relation...

Comment: ...and these values have to be adjusted between given values from the input list and values generated during first thread.

Comment: @daikini You were in a mistake concerning the author of the code. I think that now you have understood that the code you agree is mine. --- There was a error of writing in my code, I had written ``a[len(a)-1]`` instead of ``a[len(a)-i]`` in the definition of **read_b**, then the error on the first calculated value in **read_b** had persistent effect on the following calculated values. I have corrected all the code, and improved it. Think it's OK now.